# Only run command as one player? Minecraft plugin develment

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm making a command for my custom plugin, for a server. Basically what I need is the coding for making a command runnable by one or more players only.

For example what if I wanted a command /idk, but only the player SOS could use it. If anyone else used it, another command would happen, and it would send a messages "Your not SOS"!

Let's say it killed someone who tried to use the command, than sent them a message saying "Your not SOS"

Thanks!

This is my start below!

```
  {
        if (args.length != 1)
        {
            return false;
        }

        final Player player = getPlayer(args[0]);

        if (player == null)
        {
            sender.sendMessage("This player can't be found!");
            return true;
        }

//Commands and other things down here
```

Comment: To get an answer, you should ask a question.  However, if you want hints on how to do this (this is not the forum for such things but I will answer anyway) you should look at the Essentials mod as it has `sudo` to make some do something and `kill` to a kill a player as well as many other interesting commands like `kitty-cannon`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check for the name of the sender or the command itself

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args) {
    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("idk")) {
        if (sender.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("SOS")) {
            sender.sendMessage("You are SOS");
        } else {
            sender.sendMessage("You are not SOS!");
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This was very helpful, one more question, how would I add multiply commands using this. If I want /idk and /nope.

Comment: Having /idk and /nope to the same if block?

``if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("idk") || cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("nope")) {``